# How to append another file after max lines exceeded in PHP?

Tags: php

Append new file after reaching max lines in .txt file:

```php
$fpp = fopen('file1.txt', 'r');
fwrite($fpp, 'text goes here'."\n");
fclose($fpp);
```

Actually I want to append continuously **new file (file*.txt)** after 10 lines text reached in each **(file*.txt)**, I'll be grateful to those who help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Is this one block of data or are you wanting to append data (bit like an error log)?

Answer (score 0):

A better alternative to file_put_content instead of fopen. You can set the following sample code to yourself.

```
<?php
$tests = [
    "alparslan",
    "alparslan2",
    "alparslan3",
    "alparslan4",
    "alparslan5",
    "alparslan6",
    "alparslan7",
    "alparslan8",
    "alparslan9",
    "alparslan10",
    "alparslan11",
    "alparslan12",
    "alparslan13",
    "alparslan14",
    "alparslan15",
    "alparslan16",
];

$maximumLine = 10;
$filePrefixNumber = 0;
foreach($tests as $test){
    $filePath = "test_".$filePrefixNumber.".txt";
    // file write
    file_put_contents($filePath,$test."\n",FILE_APPEND);

    // maximum line and increase filePrefixNumber
    if(count(file($filePath)) >= $maximumLine){
        $filePrefixNumber++;
    }
}
```